# Find the expected value..

Tags: probability, expected-value

Hi i was having a bit of a problem understanding why the professor did what he did. I found this exercise in the solved exercise session in my university solved exercise session.

The problem goes like this:

Each time a button is pressed a machine delivers a plate of plastic material having thickness distributed(independently of the previous time) as an exponential random variable with $\gamma =2$. Pressing the key once one obtains a plate of thickness $X_1$. If $X_1 \geq \frac12 $ we can sell the plate making a profit of 1 euro  otherwise he can press the button  a second time and get a new plate $X_2$. If $X_2 \geq \frac12$ we can sell it to make a profit of 0.5 euros and if even $X_2$ is too thin then we discard everything and we gain nothing

We have to find the Expected value

I know generally how to find the expected value but i didnt get where he got some of the numbers from.
Here is what he does

Let G be the gain
$E[G]=1⋅P[G=1]+0.5*P[G=0.5] + 0⋅P[G=0]$

How to find the probabilities of the Gain G being $1$ and $0.5$ and $0$ i know how to do! THe only thing thats confusing me is how he got the $1,0.5,0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall from the definition of expected value that it is equal to $\sum x_iP(x_i)$. Here $1$, $0.5$, $0$ represent the gain of each event.

Comment: OOOOH! So its the amount gained multiplied with the probability that that event happens! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yep, exactly. It is pretty similar to a weighted average